# Assert 'must be power of 2' in VHDL?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl

I'd like:

```
entity foo is
  generic (
    DATA_WIDTH : natural; -- MUST BE POWER OF 2
    ...
  );

  ...

  assert (DATA_WIDTH & (DATA_WIDTH - 1)) = 0 report "DATA_WIDTH : MUST BE POWER OF 2" severity error;
```

While this bit-fiddling approach works in Verilog, what's the formal type-sensitive approach used in the more highly-typed VHDL?
How do I do this in VHDL?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. Your method you provided looks correct above. What's the issue?

Comment: VHDL is more sensitive to data-type issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
entity check_power_of_2 is
    generic (
        data_width : natural := 15
    );
end entity check_power_of_2;
library ieee;
use ieee.math_real.all;
architecture struct of check_power_of_2 is
begin
    process
        constant log2_of_data_width : real := log2(real(data_width));
    begin
        assert real(integer(log2_of_data_width))=log2_of_data_width
        report "data_width is not a power of 2" severity error;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: So "assert real(integer(log2(real(data_width))))=log2(real(data_width)) report ..." Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
entity check_power_of_2 is
    generic (
        data_width : natural := 16
    );
end entity check_power_of_2;
 library ieee;
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 use ieee.numeric_std.all;
 use ieee.math_real.all;
 architecture struct of check_power_of_2 is
 begin
     process
         constant bit_number : natural := natural(ceil(log2(real(data_width))))+1;
         constant data_width_vector : unsigned(bit_number-1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(data_width, bit_number);
     begin
         assert (data_width_vector and (data_width_vector-1))=0
         report "data_width is not a power of 2" severity error;
         wait;
     end process;
end architecture;
```